# Finding average highest salary

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to find the highest average sales among all the salespersons using the given table.

```
Table: Sales

Field       Type
InvoiceNo   Integer
SalesPerson Text
TotalSale   Integer
```

Sample

```
InvoiceNo   SalesPerson  TotalSale
1           Acheson      50
2           Bryant       25
3           Bennett      250
4           Acheson      50
5           Bryant       100
6           Bennett      250
```

Sample output

```
max(totalsale)
250.0000
```

I tried using: `SELECT MAX(TotalSale) FROM Sales`. My output for sample test case was 250 but it was given wrong answer verdict in an online judge.
Also, when I changed the query to : `SELECT MAX(TotalSale*1.0000) FROM Sales`,I got correct answer for sample test case but still wrong answer for other test cases.

What is meant by average here? What should be the query?

Also, this isn't from any on-going competition. It is from a practice test which you can attempt here:  https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/test/kredx-data-analyst-test/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.First you have to calculate the average **TotalSale** for each **SalesPerson** using the **AVG** function.

```
SELECT SalesPerson, AVG(TotalSale) AS 'TotalSale' 
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY SalesPerson
```

2.Find out the max value from the table generated by the above query.

```
SELECT MAX(avgSales.TotalSale)
FROM (SELECT AVG(TotalSale) AS 'TotalSale' FROM Sales GROUP BY SalesPerson) AS avgSales
```

Comment: Because your task tells you to find the maximum average sales among all the **salespersons**. You have multiple records for the same person, but their **InvoiceNo** are different, so you can't group by InvoiceNo because there will be nothing to group as there aren't records with the same InvoiceNo. The only thing that is constant is the **SalesPerson** value.

Comment: This is partially correct. The best one is by Vikas Garg and should be at Top.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT avg(TotalSale) as MaxTotal 
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY Salesperson 
ORDER BY MaxTotal desc 
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
MaxtTotal
250.0000
```

Comment: This answer appears to be the same as another answer. Repeating the information in other answers is not useful, it is just clutter. New answers to old and answered questions should add new information and new insights into the topic.

Comment: This works perfectly and should be at Top. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The average sale would use the `avg()` function:

```
select salesperson, avg(totalsale) as avg_totalsale
from sales
group by salesperson;
```

The maximum of the average can be obtained using `order by` and `limit`:

```
select avg(totalsale) as avg_totalsale
from sales
group by salesperson
order by avg_totalsale desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I am new to SQL. Will you mind me explaining these?

Why did you group by Salesperson and not invoiceno or total sale?
What is the function of limit 1?

Comment: @RizwanAnsari . . . Read the question and think about the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to answer this:

```
select avg(TotalSale) 
from Sales 
group by SalesPerson 
order by totalSale desc limit 1;
```

output:

```
avg(TotalSale)
250.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(avgsale.TotalSale) 
FROM (Select Cast(Round(Avg(TotalSale),2) as dec(10,4)) 'TotalSale' from Sales 
GROUP BY salesPerson) avgsale
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor change to @gordon-linoff 's answer to pass the sample test case.

```
select CAST(avg(totalsale) AS DECIMAL(16,4)) as avg_totalsale
from sales
group by salesperson
order by avg_totalsale desc
limit 1;
```

```
CAST(avg(totalsale) AS DECIMAL(16,4))
```

The above part will restrict the zero's in decimal place up to 4. Convert 250.00000000 to 250.0000